# Add a css class and remove it after a specified delay

Tags: jquery

I want to show some activity on a div i am sing to show some recent information and i am doing that by giving the div a color depending on the kind of notification.

I am doing this

```
$("#ru").addClass("brc").delay(500).removeClass("brc");
```

Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/vCDAh/1/

Why is this not working?.

Comment: Your JSFiddle has the div class set to "ru" instead of the id: 
<div class ="ru" class="">
If you copied it from your source code, you probably need to change that to <div id="ru" class="">

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [delay](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) function only applies to the animation queue (apart if you pass a queue you manage as second argument).

Here you must use `setTimeout` :

```
$("#ru").addClass("brc");
setTimeout(function() { $("#ru").removeClass("brc") }, 500);
```

Answer (score 2):

From the jQuery API Site http://api.jquery.com/delay/

> The .delay() method is best for delaying between queued jQuery
>   effects. Because it is limited—it doesn't, for example, offer a way to
>   cancel the delay—.delay() is not a replacement for JavaScript's native
>   setTimeout function, which may be more appropriate for certain use
>   cases.

In this case, adding classes is not an effect (and does not have a queue at all)

```
$("#ru").addClass("brc");

setTimeout(function() { 
  $("#ru").removeClass("brc");
}, 500);
```